# How to increase space between text and the line-box when using NiceTabular environment in the nicematrix package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, nicematrix, varwidth

When using the NiceTabular environment in the nicematrix package, how do I increase the space between the text and the tikz-drawn line-box on all sides of the text when using type V columns defined by varwidth?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{V{10cm}} \bfseries \large
Titre \\
\lipsum[1][1-4] 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw [rounded corners] (1-1) -| (last-|2) -- (last-|1) |- (1-1) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Dumb question but why do you use `nicematrix` to do this kind of things in the first place? There are many ways to achieve this more easily, like `tcolorbox` or even a simple Ti*k*Z environment. Is this meant to be inserted into a table?

Comment: @SebGlav. The example of the OP is an example in the manual of `nicematrix` (illustration of the use of the columns of type `V`). I agree that there is certainly other means to do such a thing.

Comment: Aha, you know the manual better than me, indeed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{\hspace{12pt}}V{10cm}@{\hspace{12pt}}} \bfseries \large
\hspace*{0.5em} Titre\hspace*{0.5em} \\
\RowStyle[cell-space-limits=6pt]{}
\lipsum[1][1-4] 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw [rounded corners] (1-1) -| (last-|2) -- (last-|1) |- (1-1) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Works ... thank you. Is there a way to provide more space to the left and right around the title 'Titre'?

Comment: I've modified my answer by adding tow `\hspace*{1em}` (on the right side, the `*` of `\hspace` is mandatory).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, and for your update. I was able to supplement your solution by adding the following to \tikz \draw: 'line width=1pt' to control line thickness as well as 'red!75!black' to add line color. Thanks again!

Comment: My final configuration is as follows: \begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{\hspace{20pt}}V{16cm}@{\hspace{20pt}}}\bfseries\large
\hspace*{0.5em} Titre\hspace*{0.5em} \\
\RowStyle[cell-space-limits=12pt]{}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners, red!75!black] (1-1) -| (last-|2) -- (last-|1) |- (1-1) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document} Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution using `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black, fonttitle=\large\bfseries,
    boxed title style={colframe=white, colback=white,},
    title=#2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{Titre}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[top=5mm]{Titre}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ... Is there a way to center your mybox? I tried \begin{center} ... \end{center}, but I get an error. Also, how do I narrow the thickness of the box line?

Comment: I was able to center the mybox using:     before=\begin{center},
    after=\end{center},
How do I adjust the thickness of the box line?

Comment: @ Ignasi - Thank you for your alternative solution, a close second to the initial solution. I have trialed both solutions, and although I intend to keep your solution (with your permission) in my quiver for possible implementation, the initial solution was a wee bit more in line with my original question, and so received my acceptance. Thank you for offering the alternative solution.

Comment: My final implementation is as follows: \newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    before=\begin{center},
    after=\end{center},
    frame code={\draw[line width=1pt]},
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    colback=white,
    colframe=BrickRed!75!black,
    coltitle=black, fonttitle=\large\bfseries,
    boxed title style={colframe=white, colback=white },
    title=#2,
    #1
}

Comment: @RosesBouquet About centering, by default a `tcolorbox` is as wide a `\linewidth`, so you don't need to center it. In case you fix a narrower width, you can add option `center` in `tcolorbox` definition. There's no need for your `before` and `after` options. An about frame thicknes, you can easily fix it with `boxrule=...`. It's default value is 0.5mm.